# Flutter: Image resizes weirdly

Tags: flutter, image, frontend, resize, crop

I have an app with a feature that allows users to upload images, and later these images are used at various points through the app. I use imagePicker to get the images, with the following method:

```
onTap: () async {
                      ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
                      final XFile? _image = await _picker.pickImage(
                        source: ImageSource.gallery,
                        imageQuality: 50,
                      );

                      if (_image == null) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text('No image was selected.')));
                      }

                      if (_image != null) {
                        print('Uploading ...');
                        Container(
                          child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                        );
                        StorageRepository().updateImage(user, _image, index);
                      }
                    },
```

One example of a widget with weird image resizing is the following:

```
SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          offset: Offset(3, 3),
                                          blurRadius: 3,
                                          spreadRadius: 3)
                                    ],
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      image: NetworkImage(voteUser!
                                          .imageUrls[state.imageUrlIndex]),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ...
                             ),
                          ),
```

In this image, you can see the guy is stretched out, making the photo look weird.

[image]

My question is, how can I make an image that consistently looks good, but will not overflow the screen? I recognize cropping the image during the upload can help, however i would then have to set widgets with variable widths and heights rather than using mediaQuery, which runs the risk of overflowing the screen. Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Boxfit.cover` it will work.

```
fit: BoxFit.cover
```